# Writing File using buffered IO vs using Goroutine

Tags: go

I am implementing a logging library using golang. I know that writing logs to file is a slow I/O operation. Then I was thinking of using goroutine to leverage the benefit of the async nature of goroutine. So that the main goroutine will not be blocked by any I/O operation. Recently, I found go library provides a [buffered I/O library](https://golang.org/src/bufio/bufio.go). I am wondering which way is the best way to implement file logging? Is there any trade off between these two designs?

Comment: Writing concurrently and buffered io are two very different concepts, in not sure what meaningful comparison you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for you reply, I am looking for which design is better to implement the logging library.

Answer (score 0):

One goroutine reads from a buffered channel and writes to a buffered writer, other goroutines send logs to that channel.